# PHP DOMDocument: getElementsbyTagName('img') isn't working

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I'm trying to grab an img tag inside a feed, in WordPress. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
/* specify the source feed   */     $rss = fetch_feed('http://www.anobii.com/rss_shelf?s=01fe251a6c442bbf8a');
/* checks obj. is created    */     if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
/* specify number of items   */     $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);
/* create an array of items  */     $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
?>
<ul>
    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>Content not available</li>';
else
    // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
    $firstContent = null;
    $firstIsSet = false;
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
    <?php
    if (!$firstIsSet) {
        $firstContent = $item->get_content();
        $firstIsSet = true;
    }
    ?>
    <?php $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($firstContent);
    $imgs = $doc->getElementsbyTagName('img');
    $res = $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $highres = str_replace("type=3", "type=4", $res);
    ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>" rel="external"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<img src="<?php print_r($highres); ?>" style="float:right">
```

`get_title()` and `get_permalink` are working ok. But `print_r($highres);` does nothing..

Maybe the problem is the rss feed is somewhat broken (see `fetch_feed` link)..?

Comment: Please set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php` and tell us if you see any errors when executing the code.

Comment: Did it.. no errors. I think the problem has to do with "non-wordpress" code (the code to grab the img tag).

Comment: Uhm, why do you supress errors in the line `@$doc->loadHTML($firstContent);`?

Comment: Nice question.. :P removed! still no error :O

Comment: Try printing the content of `$imgs` -> `print_r($imgs);`. Do you get some tags?